# Java digital-signing related files (MANIFEST.MF, *.SF, *.DSA) and their content?

Tags: java, hash, jar, digital-signature, jarsigner

**I am trying to understand what are the steps that jar and jarsigner go through when jarring up and signing up java code, to replicate parts of these steps programmatically.**

Explicitely I'd like to know what exactly goes into a .SF file, because I've read **many documents each stating something slightly different**, some examples:

- http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J9d_Jar.html

> The digest (or hash) is computed for every file in the JAR and
>   included inside the manifest, e.g.,
>
> Name: Hello.class SHA1-Digest: (a 160-bit hash value for the file)
>
> When the JAR file is signed, a signature file with extension ".SF" is
>   created in the directory META-INF. The digest value of each file is
>   signed (or encrypted) using the signer's private key. e.g.,
>
> Name: Hello.class SHA1-Digest: (digest value encrypted using signer's
>   private key)

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/intro.html

> The signature file contains digest entries for the
>   archive's files that look similar to the digest-value entries in the
>   manifest. However, while the digest values in the manifest are
>   computed from the files themselves, the digest values in the signature
>   file are computed from the corresponding entries in the manifest.
>   Signature files also contain a digest value for the entire manifest

- other sources which treat the argument in a vague and non descriptive way

**So uhm.. what does exactly a .SF file contain? How its entries are computed ?**

*Please before posting an answer, check it with an hash calculator [**like this**](http://www.webutils.pl/index.php?idx=sha1) if needed!*

Comment: You could sign a jar file then "unjar it" to see an example...

Answer (score 3):

In the .SF file, on the other hand, the digest value for a given source file is the hash of the three lines in the manifest file for the source file.

For more info, plz look
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html

Comment: checked this by writing a program that takes the entire MANIFEST content as a string, then computes SHA-1 hash on all substrings of it, then look for one that matches what is in SF file, in my case it took 4 lines, "Name:" "SHA-1 Digest:" then two empty lines.